# slider зацикливание

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Как зациклить слайдер?
При удалении элементов сверху остальные блоки сдвигаются.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/htgv2wu3/2/)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var currentPosY = parseInt($('.slider').css('transform').match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[5], 10)
  $('.slider').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0,' + (currentPosY - 130) + 'px)'
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s
}

.slider-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
    <div class="slider-item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>кнопка</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.slider').animate({"margin-top": '-=130px'}, "slow", function() {
        $(this).children().first().detach().appendTo($('.slider'));
        $(this).css('margin-top', '0px');
  });
});
```

Comment: магическую константу 130 лучше бы вынести в отдельную переменную

Comment: слайдер должен двигаться всегда в одном направлении

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуй так

Comment: спасибо, работает. Кстати вот это .slideDown(0); не нужно.
Единственный моменнт у меня все на translate работает

Comment: Точно, забыл убрать после экспериментов )

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо перемещать слайды, как то так - https://jsfiddle.net/htgv2wu3/5/

```js
var height = $('.wrapper').height(),
 $slider = $('.slider');

$('button').click(nextSlide);

function nextSlide(){
 $slider.css('transform','translate(0,'+ (-height) +'px)');
}

$slider.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
  $slider.css('transition','none');
    var $first = $('.slider-item').get(0);
    $first.remove();
    $slider.append($first);    
    $slider.css('transform','translate(0, 0)');
         
    setTimeout(function(){
        $slider.css('transition','');
    })
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slider {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s
}

.slider-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
    <div class="slider-item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Последний слайд поставил первым и спрятал.
2. По кнопке первый (спрятанный) перемещаю в конец и снимаю с него `display:none;`, а следующий слайд сворачиваю с помощью `.slideUp()`.

```js
 
var $slider = $( '.slider' );

$( 'button' ).click( function(){
  var $first = $slider.children().first();
  $first.next().slideUp();
  $first.appendTo( $slider ).show();
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s
}

.slider-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-item" style="display:none;">4</div>
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>кнопка</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо, но эффект не совсем такой. Слайды должны сменять друг друга а не налазить один на другой

Comment: @ruslik Понял, спасибо за пояснение.